# Logging not working when using MyLogger class and static methods

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging, amazon-ec2, glassfish-4

I deployed a JavaEE web app on Glassfish4 server in an EC2 instance.
Everything works fine, but when I tried to add logging capabilities I cannot find the logs.
I created a MyLogger static class just to begin (I still have to learn a lot about logging and I'm afraid this can be the cause of my failure...). This is the code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class MyLogger {

    private final String LOG_FILENAME = "/tmp/app.log";

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLogger");
    private static FileHandler fh;

    public MyLogger() {

        try {
            // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter
            fh = new FileHandler(LOG_FILENAME);
            logger.addHandler(fh);
            SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
            fh.setFormatter(formatter);

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void logInfo(String msg) {
        logger.info(msg);
    }

    public static void logWarning(String msg) {
        logger.warning(msg);
    }

    public static void logSevere(String msg) {
        logger.severe(msg);
    }
}
```

and this is the class the uses MyLogger

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class RequestsApi
 */
@WebServlet("/api/requests")
public class RequestsApi extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // set the ArrayList where to put the offers that can satisfy
    // the request
    List<Offer> goodOffers;

    Request liftRequest;

    // The Bean for the requests
    @EJB
    RequestEJB requestEjb;

    // the Bean for the offers
    @EJB
    OfferEJB offerEjb;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public RequestsApi() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         goodOffers = new ArrayList<Offer>();
         liftRequest = new Request();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<Request> listRequest = new ArrayList<Request>();

        String origin = request.getParameter("origin");
        String destination = request.getParameter("destination");

        if (origin != null) {
            Request liftRequest = new Request();
            liftRequest.setOrigin(origin);
            liftRequest.setDestination(destination);
            requestEjb.createRequest(liftRequest);
        }

        MyLogger.logSevere(origin + ", "+ destination);

        // get all the athletes in the DB
        listRequest = requestEjb.findRequests();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    List<Offer> offers = offerEjb.findOffers();
                    for (Offer offer : offers)
                        if (isGood(offer))
                            goodOffers.add(offer);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();

        // create the JSON file
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(listRequest);
        response.getWriter().append(array.toString());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String origin = request.getParameter("origin");
        final String destination = request.getParameter("destination");
        final String username = request.getParameter("username");

        liftRequest.setOrigin(origin);
        liftRequest.setDestination(destination);
        liftRequest.setRequesterUsername(username);
        requestEjb.createRequest(liftRequest);

        MyLogger.logInfo(username + ": " + origin + ", "+ destination);

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    List<Offer> offers = offerEjb.findOffers();
                    for (Offer offer : offers)
                        if (isGood(offer))
                            goodOffers.add(offer);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }

    public boolean isGood(Offer offer) throws Exception {

        return true;
    }

}
```

The servlet works fine in terms of answer to the web browser but I don't know how to get my log files.

I thought that I should have found my log file in the /tmp directory of EC2 instance, but this is not the case.

Is there anything wrong with my logger implementation or do I need to pay attention in managing files in EC2 with a particular logging configuration?

---

**New info**
I tried the same approach with a standalone Java application on my PC and it works.
It actually seems an issue in managing files on EC2 instances

---

**New info**
on EC2 logging is working properly with a standalone Java application. So the problem is not with EC2, but with how logging is managed in a JavaEE web application

---

**New info**
Putting the content of MyLogger into RequestsApi everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: it is about basic knowledge of static methods and constructors :-(
I thought that just when a class is referenced, even if a static method is called and there is no need for an object instance, the constructor is called.
This is not true and so no handlers where added to the logger.